# Wordpress Dashboard widget

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress, dashboard

Previous developer of our website had very weird approach by creating widget in core wordpress files in /wp-admin/includes/dashboard.php

This widget "top sentence" is asking for sentence and URL from dashboard and posting it in header of main page.

How to create this dashboard widget, but not to write it WordPress core files and to be compatible with Wordpress 3.8.1 and Wordpress Multisite so some of the sites can also have their individual "top sentence"?

```
    <div id="dashboard-widgets" class="metabox-holder<?php echo $columns_css; ?>">
        <div id="top_sentence" class="postbox" style='margin-left: 5px; width: 98%;'>
<?php
    require_wp_db();


    global $wpdb;

    $topSentenceTitle = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT settings_value FROM wp_settings WHERE settings_name like 'top sentence title';"  ) );
    $topSentenceUrl = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT settings_value FROM wp_settings WHERE settings_name like 'top sentence url';" ) );

    $topSentenceResult = "";
    if ( $_SESSION['top-sentence-updated'] == 'true' )
    {
        $_SESSION['top-sentence-updated'] = '';
        $topSentenceResult = 'Updated';
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#top-sentence-result').fadeIn(1000).delay(1000).fadeOut(1000);
});
</script>
<?php
    }

    if ( is_blog_admin() && current_user_can('edit_posts') )
    {
?>

    <h3 class='hndle'><span>Top sentence</span></h3>
    <div class="inside">
        <form action='action.php' method='post' style='margin:0;padding:0;'>
        //action.php doesn't exist in WordPress 3.8.1
        <div style='float: left; width: 100%; margin-bottom: 3px;'>

            <h4 id="top-sentence-title" style='float: left;font-size: 12px; font-weight: normal; padding-top: 5px; text-align: right; width: 5.5em;'>
                <label for="top-sentence-title-input" style='font-family: "Lucida Grande",Verdana,Arial;margin-right: 10px;vertical-align: middle;cursor: pointer;'>Sentence:</label>
            </h4>
            <div style='margin: 0 0 1em 5em;'>
                <input style='float:right;margin:0;width:99%;' id="top-sentence-title-input" type="text" value="<?= $topSentenceTitle ?>" autocomplete="off" name="top-sentence">
            </div>
            <div style='clear: both;margin-bottom:5px;'></div>

            <h4 id="top-sentence-url" style='float: left;font-size: 12px; font-weight: normal; padding-top: 5px; text-align: right; width: 5.5em;'>
                <label for="top-sentence-url-input" style='font-family: "Lucida Grande",Verdana,Arial;margin-right: 10px;vertical-align: middle;cursor: pointer;'>URL:</label>
            </h4>
            <div style='margin: 0 0 1em 5em;'>
                <input style='float:right;margin:0;width:99%;' id="top-sentence-url-input" type="text" value="<?= $topSentenceUrl ?>" autocomplete="off" name="top-sentence-url">
            </div>

        </div>

        <div id='top-sentence-result' style="display: none;margin-left:6em;float: left;margin-top: 5px;color: red;"><span><?= $topSentenceResult ?></span></div>
        <div id="publishing-action" style='float:right; width: 100px;'>
            <input id="publish_sentence" class="button-primary" type="submit" value="Publish" tabindex="5" accesskey="p" name="do_publish_sentence">
        </div>
        </form>
        <div style='clear: both;'></div>
    </div>
<?php
    }
?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what [Plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin) are for. Simply create a PHP file, put a basic plugin header and move all your custom code to it:

```
<?php
/** 
 * Plugin Name: My dashboard widget
 */
```

Upload to `wp-content/plugins` folder and activate it on a single site or network activate on Multisite.

You can start creating a very simple plugin using the Codex sample code found in the page [Dashboard Widgets API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Dashboard_Widgets_API). Also, you'll find many examples of Dashboard widgets at [WordPress Answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=wp_add_dashboard_widget).